# Java - renameTo

Tags: java

Pongo el código antes que nada y luego explico el problema. No encuentro qué es lo que puede fallar.

```
String nuevoNombre = archivo.getParentFile() + "\\proc_" + archivo.getName();

File newfileName = new File(nuevoNombre);

return archivoProcesado.renameTo(newfileName);
```

Si lo ejecuto desde mi máquina, funciona bien. El tema es que cuando se ejecuta desde un servidor (tiene jre 1.4) `renameTo` devuelve `false`, y no renombra el archivo.

No arroja ninguna excepción, ni seguridad ni nada. Simplemente `false` y no renombra. ¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ocurrir esto y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3):

El comportamiento esperado de ese método difere de lo esperado en las mas modernas.
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4073756

Mas adelante Oracle cambió el comportamiento para lo que conocemos hoy día como renameTo

Puede utilizar una alternativa, borrando el antiguo fichero y guardando el nuevo en la nueva localización o con el nuevo nombre.

Comment: En realidad (mira la "Resolution: Not an Issue" y los comentarios al final) eso no es considerado un bug, es el comportamiento esperado.

Answer (score 1):

En los [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) de `File.renameTo` se advierte que

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists.

Sobre todo, se me ocurre que deberías ver si estás intentando mover el archivo
entre diferentes particiones. En tal caso, es muy probable que falle. También si el archivo origen o destino está abierto por otro proceso.

Como sugieren [en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087743/how-to-rename-a-file-to-another-file-system) la alternativa es copiar y borrar a mano, o usar [FileUtils.moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) de Apache Commons.

Aunque probablemente ya lo sepas, a estas alturas jre 1.4 es una versión muy vieja (si está en tu poder, deberías tratar de migrar a una versión más moderna).

Answer (score 1):

Cambiar de nombre a un archivo en Java

La clase java.io.File implementa el método renameTo que permite cambiar de nombre a un archivo.

Ejemplo, cambiar el nombre de un archivo  “ejemplo1.txt” a “ejemplo2.txt”:

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.io.File;

/**

 * @author SoftMolina

 */

public class RenombrarArchivo {

    public static void main(String args[]){

            try{
            File archivo1 = new File("ejemplo1.txt");

            File archivo2 = new File("ejemplo2.txt");

            boolean estatus = archivo1.renameTo(archivo2);

            if (!estatus) {

                System.out.println("Error no se ha podido cambiar el nombre al archivo");

            }else{

                System.out.println("Cambio de nombre del archivo exitoso");

            }
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);

           }

    }

}
```

El cambio de nombre del archivo puede fallar por que el archivo no existe, el usuario no tiene permisos para cambiar el nombre, o el archivo esta en uso.

[Ver mas aqui](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/13/cambiar-de-nombre-mover-eliminar-o-copiar-un-archivo-en-java/)